# nonspecific enum function parameter

Tags: c++, function, generics, parameters, enums

Im trying to write a function that takes an enum as a parameter, just as a function would take an int or bool etc.

I am using c++ so for example 
void Func (enum Blah, int blah);

any idea how I can let the function take a nonspecific enum as an argument?

I know I could just cast enums as ints and pass them through like this

enum foo{BAR};

void Func (int myenum, int blah);
Func ((int)BAR, 0)
However I don't want to be able to pass through anything but an enum.

I have heard of generics, I'm not sure if they are the answer because I couldn't find any definitive information on them.

So either some code or a link that would help me would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: XY? Im not sure what that is

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename Enum>
void Func (Enum blah, int fleh)
{
  static_assert(std::is_enum<Enum>::value, "Only enums are allowed here");
}
```